# How do I track why X11 keyboard shortcuts don't work?

Tags: x11

I am on Arch Linux. I am completely stuck trying to figure out why some of the key combinations work on regular DELL 101 key usb keyboard in X11, but not on the mechanical gaming one. I have 2 keyboards (ttesports and Corsair K60) which malfunction in X11 exactly the same way: all works, except <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> and CapsLock LED.

Keyboard is configured by the following section in config file:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        Driver       "evdev"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us,ru"
        Option "XkbOptions" "grp:lalt_lshift_toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection
```

In order to diagnose, I plugged in both DELL and ttesports keyboards at the same time. I'm trying to see what's different when I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. I use `xev` to track what events are generated. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, both keyboard generate identical output (except serial), but only the DELL one switches to VT2, the ttesports leaves the screen as-is. Output is:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x287, subw 0x0, time 74514015, (2239,-23), root:(2385,850),
    state 0xc, keycode 68 (keysym 0x1008fe02, XF86Switch_VT_2), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

As far as I could tell, both keyboards work identically in console mode (not X11 that is), in a sense that every shortcut works fine as far as I could tell.

How do I track why one keyboard switches the VT, and the other doesn't?

**EDIT:** I also tried to track the CapsLock behavior. I used `showkey` command on the console. It shows keycode 58 press/release when I use CapsLock button on either keyboard. However:

- Pressing <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> on either keyboard toggles CapsLock state.
- Pressing <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> on DELL keyboard makes CalsLock LED toggle on DELL keyboard only.
- Pressing <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> on ttesports keyboard toggles actual CapsLock state, but CapsLock LED doesn't toggle on neither of 2 keyboards.
- Pressing <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> on ttesports keyboard, when CapsLock LED is on on DELL keyboard does not turn it off, althoug it does turn off actual CapsLock state.